# How do I make Activity to work inside fragment?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, kotlin

When I select the chillzone fragment from the Navigation Drawer I am able to switch the fragments but When I try to select something from the BottomNavigationView nothing happens.

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**chillzone_fragment.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.chillzone.ChillZoneActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="172dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="172dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="356dp"
        android:text="@string/chillzone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ChillZoneActivity**

```java
package com.rishabhdeepsingh.metaapp.ui.chillzone

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.rishabhdeepsingh.metaapp.R

class ChillZoneActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView
    private lateinit var textMessage: TextView
    private val onNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                textMessage.setText(R.string.title_home)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
                textMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Dashboard", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_notifications -> {
                textMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Notifications", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view)
        println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!~~~~~~~~~~")
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        textMessage = findViewById(R.id.message)
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    }
}
```

**ChillZoneFragment.kt**

```java
package com.rishabhdeepsingh.metaapp.ui.chillzone

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.rishabhdeepsingh.metaapp.R

class ChillZoneFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.chillzone_fragment, container, false)
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```java
package com.rishabhdeepsingh.metaapp.ui

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import com.rishabhdeepsingh.metaapp.R
import com.rishabhdeepsingh.metaapp.ui.chillzone.ChillZoneFragment


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        )
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, HomeFragment())
                .commit()
            navView.setCheckedItem(R.id.home)
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_home -> {
                // Handle the camera action
                supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, HomeFragment())
                    .commit()
            }
            R.id.nav_chillzone -> {
                supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, ChillZoneFragment())
                    .commit()
            }
            R.id.nav_slideshow -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_tools -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_share -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_send -> {

            }
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
}
```

I expected that the Toast message should appear corresponding to the BottomNavigationView button I select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BottomNavigationView` related code is in the `ChillZoneActivity`. It needs to be in the `ChillZoneFragment`.

```
class ChillZoneFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView
    private lateinit var textMessage: TextView
    private val onNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                textMessage.setText(R.string.title_home)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
                textMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Dashboard", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_notifications -> {
                textMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Notifications", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chillzone_fragment, container, false)
        bottomNavigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view)
        textMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.message)
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)
        return view
    }
}
```

P.S - You can't make an activity 'work' inside a fragment. That's just not how it works. Fragments are contained in the activity, never the other way around.

> A `Fragment` represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in a `FragmentActivity`. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).
>
> A fragment must always be hosted in an activity and the fragment's lifecycle is directly affected by the host activity's lifecycle.

Refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) for further details.

Comment: So should I create a new activity for the ChillZone?

Comment: Go through the [Codelabs for Android Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/courses/fundamentals-training/toc-v2), it should help you get a good grasp of the basics of Android development.

Comment: Here's the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-create-an-activity/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#0) that explains how to create and transition to activities.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like bottom navigation listener is not being set properly
try switching this:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)
```

to:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Android Fragment is the part of activity, it is also known as sub-activity. There can be more than one fragment in an activity. Fragments represent multiple screen inside one activity.
>
> Android fragment lifecycle is affected by activity lifecycle because fragments are included in activity.
>
> Each fragment has its own life cycle methods that is affected by activity life cycle because fragments are embedded in activity.
>
> The FragmentManager class is responsible to make interaction between fragment objects.

You can't add activity inside fragment.

I hope It helps you!